# Istio bookinfo makes minikube to time out any request

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have been try to evaluate Istio on my development environment but so far I have not been able to run the bookinfo application. I downloaded istio version 0.7.1 and I installed it without any issue.

To verify that the installation was fine, I ran the command ***watch kubectl get pod --all-namespaces*** and the output shows that all pods are running fine.

```
Every 2.0s: kubectl get pod --all-namespaces                              ubuntu: Tue Apr 24 04:21:00 2018

NAMESPACE      NAME                                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
istio-system   grafana-7b8f9b9b4f-7cd4r                1/1       Running   0          1h
istio-system   istio-ca-75fb7dc8d5-mhrd5               1/1       Running   0          1h
istio-system   istio-ingress-8546966f58-m4zt6          1/1       Running   0          1h
istio-system   istio-mixer-566f68f5d6-rj8dd            3/3       Running   0          1h
istio-system   istio-pilot-fd8fb6957-xfkkr             2/2       Running   0          1h
istio-system   prometheus-6c54fc5cf-pjjdn              1/1       Running   0          1h
istio-system   servicegraph-64567d6467-hq8gn           1/1       Running   0          50m
istio-system   zipkin-78d44687f9-jhr6b                 1/1       Running   0          50m
kube-system    etcd-minikube                           1/1       Running   0          2h
kube-system    kube-addon-manager-minikube             1/1       Running   0          2h
kube-system    kube-apiserver-minikube                 1/1       Running   0          2h
kube-system    kube-controller-manager-minikube        1/1       Running   0          2h
kube-system    kube-dns-86f4d74b45-dlmbk               3/3       Running   0          2h
kube-system    kube-proxy-98kl7                        1/1       Running   0          2h
kube-system    kube-scheduler-minikube                 1/1       Running   0          2h
kube-system    kubernetes-dashboard-5498ccf677-5bvdh   1/1       Running   0          2h
kube-system    storage-provisioner                     1/1       Running   0          2h
```

Then, I ran the command ***kubectl create -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f samples/bookinfo/kube/bookinfo.yaml)*** to deploy the bookinfo app. However, after executing this command, any request to minikube fails with timeout error such as:

```
watch kubectl get pod --all-namespaces

Error from server (Timeout): the server was unable to return a response in the time allotted, but may stil
l be processing the request (get pods)
```

Also, I can not access the minikube dashboard, I get a 500 error.

have you seen this error before? how can I debug this issue?

My developer environment is:

```
Node: Ubuntu 17.10 VM (To be clear my laptop is running Windows and I have a VM with Ubuntu with : 8Gb of RAM, 4 Processors and 80Gb of disk)
Istio : version 0.7.1
kubectl version
Client Version: 
        version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.1", GitCommit:"d4ab47518836c750f9949b9e0d387f20fb92260b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-04-12T14:26:04Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 1):

The default memory for minikube is 2GB, you need a larger value for bookinfo. Try to start minikube with:

```
minikube start --memory 4096
```